# HardeningKitty: Include the machine information from the exported CSV file

Tags: shell, automation, powershell-cmdlet

We are currently testing the HardeningKitty to automate checking our computer policy, however we want to export the result to a csv file and it is successful but we want to include the machine information that the code of HardeningKitty has. But I didn't know how to start.

Here is the link of HardeningKitty
https://github.com/ataumo/policies_hardening_interface

And here is the code for running and exporting the result to CSV file

***Invoke-HardeningKitty -Mode Audit -FileFindingList finding_list_cis_microsoft_windows_server_2022_21h1_1.0.0_machine.csv -Report  -ReportFile 'C:\Users\Joanna V\Desktop\HardeningKitty-master\cis_result2.csv'***

**Note: The script above is running however I want to add the machine information shown from the attached image to the result CSV file
[Here is the machine information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNwuY.png)**